# What Django version will be in the next Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: django, ubuntu

I'm currently running a bunch of Django apps on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, but I'm expecting to upgrade the OS to 14.04 LTS when it's released.. As Ubuntu 12.04 LTS comes with the rather old Django 1.3 version, I expect there to be some app changes I need to do for my apps to keep working (deprecated APIs etc).

Comment: You shouldn't really be depending on the system-provided version of Django, since it is frequently out of date and may not keep up with security patches. You should install the current version with `pip`, preferably inside a virtualenv.

Comment: @DanielRoseman AFAIK it doesn't auto-update when there are new security updates etc.. and I don't have the time subscribing to newslists for updates for tons of apps. It would be a devops nightmare.

Comment: What, more of a nightmare than having your site hacked because you didn't install a security release?

Comment: @DanielRoseman system-provided packages are updated with security releases automatically.. which is the whole point. So not sure where you're trying to go.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about predicting release cycles of 3rd party software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like 1.6.1 will be supported.

Source: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/django-admin.1.html

Answer (score 3):

The answer *to your question* is Django 1.6.1, [according to UbuntuPackages](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/trusty/main/base/python-django).

As said by @Odif, you don't need to depend on your Operating System actually. Most of the people are using `pip` today to install Django. It's generally a bad idea to rely on distribution repositories for Python modules.

You can get the Django version you want with `pip install`:

```
pip install Django==1.5   # will install the 1.5.5 today (in April 2014)
pip install Django        # will install the 1.6.2 today (in April 2014)
```

Or even upgrade to the last one, if you have already Django installed :

```
pip install Django --upgrade
```

You should also take a look at how works the [conventional requirements.txt](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/1.1/requirements.html). With this method, you can keep your system updated with automated task, and it's not a *nightmare* for your sysops.

Plus, keep developing on old version (Django 1.3 here) can be dangerous, since this version isn't maintain for 2 or 3 years now. Django has it's own LTS system, and currently the **LTS version is Django 1.4**. The migration from 1.3 to 1.6 will be boring for you, and you can avoid that by making small updates each year.
You should stay up to date, and why not start focusing on the migration to Django 1.7, in mid-May which will contain a lot of cool new stuffs ;)

Comment: The [documentation itself](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter02.html) advises packages over pip. On Ubuntu it is `python-django`.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa It is true that it can give you security update everytime you use `apt-get upgrade`. But you won't get new major release. For example, Django 1.7 will never be in Ubuntu 14.04 repositories.

Comment: Maxime, since 14.04 is an LTS release the likelihood is high for further versions to be packaged. There are also third party PPAs, from which you may already install Python 3.4 and later versions.

Comment: Anyway, at high level in Python development, you will always use pip, since it works very well with virtualenv and such things ;) My opinion is `apt-get` is fine if you are discovering but if you go further, you should with pip.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever version you install in it. Just remove the package and install whatever version you want from pypi or django homepage.

You do not have to depend on ubuntu packages in case of django or its apps.

Comment: This is not the issue. Of course I could compile whatever version from a bleeding edge branch and run it. I want a stable release and without a devops nightmare, hence automated updates for security patches etc. Which installing from a webpage certainly won't give me.

Comment: @Niklas9 I can't believe it! Using system's builtin django is the devops nightmare.

Comment: Why is that, @Leonardo.Z?